# Get number of days from today JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering what the best way of doing this is. I am trying to have an estimated delivery time script where in the html on the page I have: 2

the 2 number will change per page but this will be the ammount of days delivery takes, now I would like another div's contents to show [ammount] of days from the date today: Friday 26th

getting the div's etc will be easy however I have no idea what kind of function I could use to get a date countdown. Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: please look any javascript Date() tutorial or reference. It's really a basic thing. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools.com: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @BenM +1 for referencing w3fools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very simple procedure to add days to a date. Here's a simple snippet:

```
// Get the current date
var now = new Date();
// Add three days
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 3);
// Log the updated Date object to the console
console.log(now); //= Sat Jul 27 2013 16:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

I thought this whole thing was quite interesting, so I took the liberty to create the more advanced script that takes work hours, weekends and special dates (i.e. holidays) into consideration:

```
// Current date/time
var now = new Date();
// Placeholder for delivery time
var deliveryDate;
// Amount of days to deliver
var deliveryDays = 2;
// Working hours (in UTC)
var workingHours = [8, 17];

// Non-delivery days/dates
// Must match the format returned by .toString(): 
// Mon Sep 28 1998 14:36:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
var nonDelivery = [
    "Sun",
    "Sat",
    "Dec 24",
    "Dec 25",
    "Dec 31",
    "Jan 1"
];

// Create a regular expression
var rxp = new RegExp(nonDelivery.join("|"));

// addDay holds the amount of days to add to delivery date
var addDay = deliveryDays;

// Add an extra day if outside of working hours
var currentHour = now.getUTCHours();
if (currentHour < workingHours[0] || 
    currentHour > workingHours[1]) {
    addDay++;
}

// Let's create our delivery date
while (!deliveryDate) {
    // Add day(s) to delivery date
    now.setDate(
        now.getDate() + addDay
    );
    deliveryDate = now;
    if (rxp.test(deliveryDate)) {
        addDay = 1;
        deliveryDate = false;
    }
}

// Function to get ordinal
function nth(d) {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';
  switch (d % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
} 

// Now lets format
var locale = "en-GB"; // Our locale
var day = deliveryDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { day: "numeric" });
var weekday = deliveryDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: "long" });

// Log the results to the console
console.log(weekday + " " + day + nth(day));
```

Comment: Awesome! very simple indeed thanks, will accept the answer in 6 minutes :)

Comment: @SimonStaton Note that this will add 24 hours. You'd proabaly want something more advanced that takes weekends and maybe even holidays into consideration.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that too, I will have a look around but at least this is a starting point, Would it be possible to convert 'now' into a date like "Friday 26th July" ?

Comment: @SimonStaton yes, look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for a full list of functions. you could use `now.toDateString()` to get pretty close to what you want.

Comment: @SimonStaton There we go! :D

Comment: @MikeCorcoran You shouldn't refer to w3scools. [See w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Instead, refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Okay last thing to ask, I am fine looking at it myself but you may know more as you wrote it ;) it works great in chrome but sadly not in IE

Comment: @SimonStaton Ah yes... That's because `toLocaleDateString` is not supported until IE11, so I guess you'll have to find another way to format it :(